# Is there a way to use south for migration , and not lose data?

Tags: database, django, migration, django-south

I used South as the migration tool, but i dint know it will format all my db ! 
I dont want to lose my db .

Comment: The whole point of South is to avoid losing data when you migrate your db.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose data" and "format my db"?  What steps did you take that led you to this situation?  We need detail!

Comment: all your db are belong to South!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to format your data, you can integrate existing apps/tables:

http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#converting-existing-apps

Read through the docs before using it.

Comment: I used it on my existing app only using manage.py convert_to_south myapp which automatically applies first migration to my app .

Comment: Then i added a field in my model and did " manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto" . Is this not suppposed to work

Comment: And after that you should run `manage.py migrate my_app` and the field will be added to database.

Answer (score 0):

South shouldn't trash your data.  But a Django gotcha in general to be aware of is that any initial_data fixtures will get imported whenever you do a syncdb, so bewore of leaving those files hanging around.